# Как правильно экранировать метасимволы в регулярных выражениях?

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Я читаю мануал и там вроде бы все просто, но у меня почему то не работает и спросить кроме как у Вас мне неукого.
  Я выполняю задачку суть которой написать регулярное выражение для валидации IP.

Я написал следующее выражение: `([0-9]|[1-9][1-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])` для того что бы проверить, что число в диапазоне от `0-255` но когда я решил добавить к нему точку экранировав её, то выходит ошибка.

```
([0-9]|[1-9][1-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.
Solution.java:18: error: illegal escape character
public String pattern = "([0-9]|[1-9][1-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.";
                                                                            ^
```

1 error

Comment: во второй группе `[1-9][1-9]` надо `0-9` во вторых скобках

Comment: а так пару слешей вместо одного впишите `\\.`

Comment: спасибо за внимательность, я и не заметил

Comment: 2 слеша помогли, теперь все заработало!

Comment: оформил своей первый ответ с меткой [tag:java] :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вы правильно отметили, для экранирования в регулярных выражениях следует использовать обратный слэш `\`.  Однако, поскольку регулярное выражение представлено в виде строки, то `\` сам является управляющим символом строки (а-ля `\n`,`\t` и т.п), и его также  необходимо экранировать.
В итоге следует использовать двойной обратный слэш `\\.` При этом, следует понимать, что это имеет место быть, если регулярное выражение представлено в виде строкового литерала. Если же вы его получите из внешнего источника (считаете  из файла и пользовательского ввода), то там двойной слэш, конечно, не нужен.

зы: `[0-9][0-9]` можно записать как `\d{2}`